# Блок "поделиться" от Yandex - ajax загрузка

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Добрый день.

Подскажите пожалуйста, куда копать:
Есть страница с постами. Под каждым постом использую блок "поделиться" от яндекса со стандартными настройками.
При пролистывании до конца списка ajax'ом грузится еще несколько постов и тд. Начиная со 2й партии подгружаемых постов блок яндекса перестает грузиться.

П.С.
Заранее спасибо за намерение помочь!

Comment: интересно зачем же на странице списка постов эти кнопки? они ведь на одну и ту же страницу будут вести или нет? он реально расшарит ссылку на пост?

Comment: Я в цикле через тот же аякс к ним подцепляю параметр "data-url" с уникальным линком. На странице Навального (navalny.com) аналогично сделано!

Comment: А ошибки какие-то начинают вываливаться? Я еще не достаточно овладел экстрасенсорными навыками, покажи хоть консоль или код

Comment: А вообще стоит почитать доку https://tech.yandex.ru/share/doc/dg/api-docpage/

Comment: Почитал. Не помогло. Зато помог другой сервис, гораздо более легкий по объему и с размещением скрипта на своем хосте. share42

Answer (score 3):

Аяксовая догрузка постов происходит у вас наверняка с соответствующими javascript-events. К одному из таких событий (`ajax:success`, например) вам нужно привязать скрипт инициализации блока с кнопками:

```
var share = Ya.share2('my-share', {
    content: {
        url: 'https://yandex.com'              
    }
    // здесь вы можете указать и другие параметры
});
```

Подробнее: https://tech.yandex.ru/share/doc/dg/api-docpage/

В вашем случае - у каждого подгруженного поста уже будет `div`-блок яндекса с нужными параметрами в `data`-атрибутах. Вам останется только через них получать данные в скрипте инициализации:

```
var share = Ya.share2('my-share', {
    content: {
        image: $('#my-share').attr('data-image')
        url: $('#my-share').attr('data-url')
        ...
    }
});
```

Где `my-share` - это ID блока. В вашем случае алгоритм такой:

- Аяксово получаете html с новыми постами
- Проходитесь по всем блокам "Поделиться" в них (например, через класс `ya-share2`)
- У каждого блока узнаете ID (он должен быть заранее присвоен и быть уникальным) и запускаете инициализатор Ya.share2()

Comment: не знаю почему этот ответ не зачтен, но он мне помог! спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Нашел совсем костыльное решение
после успеха подгрузки еще раз тяну скрипт с яндекса в в пустой див типа **yashare_reload**

```
$('.yashare_reload').html('<script src="https://yastatic.net/share2/share.js"><\/script>');
```

это единственно что меня спасло(